# How do I structure authentication with a social IdP?

Tags: asp.net, xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

My system works as follows;

I have an ASP.Net RESTful API server, which contains a user database.
I also have a Xamarin.Forms application, with a registration and login page.

What I want is to have the ability to authenticate a login using a social IdP, and then, if that user has not been logged in before, register that user in my local database.

I have been reading up on how to implement OAuth 2.0 with OpenID Connect to authenticate my users with a social IdP, however, I cannot seem to wrap my head arround it. From what I've read, I shouldn't use an Access token for authentication, since that i what the ID token is for, however, I have also read that the only intended purpose for an ID token, is the client.

My problem then is, how can I make sure that calls made to my ASP.Net server, has been made by "real person", and how do I determine who makes the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access token will be used determine whether the client application was authorized by a user to access a resource. The concept of ID token comes from OpenID Connect. Main purpose of the ID token is to authenticate the user to the client application (i.e. letting the client application know that the person who authorized the access is a valid person).

To do this, you have to validate the ID token. This can be done using third party libraries such as nimbusds or auth0. You can validate the signature of the token verify the integrity of the token and check the claims included in the token (by comparing them with expected values) to verify the user details. Also, you can add custom claims (any claim that is specific for your application/implementation) to the tokens through your identity provider so that you'll be able to validate those particular claims in order to verify the user.

Comment: Allright, so when I have validated the user at the login stage, how do I do the rest of my calls, for example a call to GET groups? Will I then keep parsing the ID token to verify the user's authenticity, or should I create my own "session token" which I give the user at the login?

I'm guessing it would be quite unsafe not to require continous authentication thoughout the use of the app?

Comment: Allocating a session token for the user would be a good idea, I suppose. But if you want, you can keep parsing the ID token to verify claims at each step. But keep in mind that the overhead for decoding and validating over and over would be high.